# difference between carries and possess

Tags: word-choice, difference

> Am I to understand that his new post _______ no responsibility with it at all?

Which answer fits the blank best? Carries or possesses?

And for what reason? Idiom or grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal English responsibilities are generally *borne*.

The verb *to bear* means:

> to carry the weight of; support ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bear))

In your sentence, "carries" is preferable, being the closest to "bears".

Answer (score 0):

> As verbs the difference between carry and possess is that carry is (lb) to lift (something) and take it to another place; to transport (something) by lifting while possess is to have; to have ownership of. [Source](https://wikidiff.com/possess/carry)

So best to use is "carries", as you usually "carry responsibility", not so much of "possessing responsibility". Think of responsibility as something you have to "hold up":

> responsibility = heavy load
>
> You have to *carry* that heavy load